# SwiftUI How to Call a Function Daily?

Tags: swift, function, date, method-call

Is there a way to call a function every day? Or at least the first time an app is opened each day? I would like to automatically update a list of variables every day but not sure how to do so.

I think I would be able to do this by creating a reference variable that holds the current date, then compare it to the "Date()", but I don't know how to prevent the reference variable from automatically updating to the new date. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A variable will only update if you code it to do so.  However writing a "last start" date to UserDefaults might be a better solution so its persisted between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a check every time the app is open. To store the reference variable, you could use UserDefaults (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults).
For example, you could write a function like this

```
func check() -> Bool {
        if let referenceDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "reference") as? Date {
            // reference date has been set, now check if date is not today
            if !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(referenceDate) {
                // if date is not today, do things
                // update the reference date to today
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "reference")
                return true
            }
        } else {
            // reference date has never been set, so set a reference date into UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "reference")
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

to use the function

```
if check() {
    // update your list of variables
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

UserDefaults will persist and keep your reference variable from changing unintentionally.